# Issue with JQuery changing Select Bracket value

Tags: javascript, php, html, select, tags

On my site, the user selects a person, and when the selection is made, it populates demographics about that patient below, but gives the user the options to change each demographic value.  I have an html select statement for a "Prep RN" that is populated from a table of RNs when the form is loaded, but when I select a patient, I can't get it to change the select to the RN that is stored in the database and is contained in the list:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'php/pullselectedpatient.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    data: {Patient_UID: tempPatient_UID},
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.Prep_RN == 'Unassigned') {
            //if unassigned, set option to unassigned
            $('#selectpreprn').val('Unassigned');
        } else {
            //if assigned, change to selected RN
            $('#selectpreprn').val(data.Prep_RN);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("ajax call failed.");
    }
});
```

This code fills the option list successfully, but in case it's part of the problem, here it is:

```
<label for='selectpreprn'>Prep RN: </label>
<select id="selectpreprn">
    <option value="empty"></option>
    <?php
        require('php/pullrns.php');
        //loop and add the patients to the drop down list
        foreach($result_rns->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC) as $row) {
            echo "<option value='", $row['RN_UID'], "'>", $row['RN_UID'], "</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

This results with the select filled with a 'blank', 'Unassigned', and then 3 names to choose from.

Also, this is my first time posting to this site (which is amazingly helpful), so I hope I provided everything.  I have spent at least 3 hours trying different things to make this work.

To reiterate, the problem is that it doesn't select the option in the select tag when the patient is selected.  It just stays blank.

Comment: Let debug it, use `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` to check if you got correct attribute. You can add the result you see in your question.

Comment: What are the actual contents of "data"?

Comment: Figured it out - Actually, of course after making this post and moving to the next part of the page, I figured it out.  I had copied and pasted this block for another section, and in that section, I didn't change the selector and it was overwriting with null, and now it works perfectly.  Story of my life!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works as intended, the issue was further down my page where I was inadvertently overwriting this selector.  I copied and pasted similar code, and it got me in trouble =(